# Passing data between programs in Haskell

Tags: haskell, compilation, tree

I'm doing two programs in Haskell, which one of them provides a tree filled with values.

The other program has to get the same tree now filled. I searched about it, but i haven't found something about how to do something like it.

For example i execute ./Generate and it saves the tree with values. Then i execute ./Work and it works with the values of the tree. Can somebody please help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way may be

```
data MyData = ... deriving (Read, Show)
```

producer

```
makeMyData :: MyData
makeMyData = ....

main = writeFile "output.data" (show makeMyData)
```

consumer

```
ioUseMyData :: MyData -> IO ()
ioUseMyData myData = ....

main = readFile "output.data" >>= ioUseMyData . read
```

you can use standard input/output using `getContents` and `putStrLn`.

Complete example:

```
-- probably as module
data Tree = Node { value :: Int
                 , left  :: Tree
                 , right :: Tree
                 }
          | Empty
            deriving (Read, Show)

-- your producer program
producerProgram = do

    let makeTree = Node 3 (Node 5 Empty Empty) (Node 7 Empty Empty)
    writeFile "output.data" (show makeTree)

-- your consumer program
consumerProgram = do

    let ioUseTree t = do

            let countNodes Empty = 0
                countNodes (Node _ l r) = 1 + countNodes l + countNodes r

            putStrLn $ "Tree with " ++ show (countNodes t) ++ " nodes"

    readFile "output.data" >>= ioUseTree . read

-- simulate call both
main = do

    -- produce
    producerProgram

    -- consume
    consumerProgram
```

result

```
Tree with 3 nodes
```

replacing

```
writeFile "output.data" (show makeTree)
```

by

```
print makeTree
```

and

```
readFile "output.data" >>= ioUseTree . read
```

by

```
getContents >>= ioUseTree . read
```

you can use pipes (`bash`, `cmd.exe`, ...)

```
$ ./producer | ./consumer
Tree with 3 nodes
```

Comment: Of course @AlexeyShmalko you are right but I have tried be simplest. Step by step ;)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is: don't use 2 separate programs. If you really need 2 separate programs then there are 3 things you will need to choose:

1. A way of converting the tree into a `String` or `ByteString`
2. A way of sending the string or bytestring to the other program
3. A way of converting the `String` or `ByteString` back into a tree

For #1 and #3: it's probably easiest to use `show` and `read`, but you can also define your own functions if you want as long as they both define the same format.

For #2: if the 2 programs are meant to be run separately then you have no choice: you have to use a file. The easiest way to do so is using the `writeFile` and `readFile` functions. If the 2 programs are meant to be run simultaneously you can also use the functions in [`Network.Socket`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/network-2.6.1.0/docs/Network-Socket.html)

Comment: #2 ... no choice. Really ? file is obviously the easiest but there other alternatives, sockets, shared memory etc ...

Comment: If 2 programs run separately, all sockets and memory owned by first one will be unavailable when second program runs. Jeremy stated that you can use `Network.Socket` if programs run simultaneously.